# How to override maven property at runtime for a specific module?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml, maven-plugin

Lets say my project has multiple sub-modules and the structure is something like this:

```
Parent
 - Submodule-A
 - Submodlue-B
 - Submodule-C
```

Now both parent and child poms have the same maven property defined in their pom.xml

```
<properties>
  <custom.property>some-value</custom.property>
</properties>
```

If I run the below command, this would override the value for both parent and its child module

```
mvn <phase|goals> -Dcustom.property=some-other-value
```

**But How do I override this property only for a specific sub-module's pom?**

Comment: Shouldn't that work exactly the same way?

Comment: @geanakuch what if <custom.property> is present in both parent and child pom? How do I enable override only for a specific child module and not for parent or any other modules ? I've edited the question, perhaps I missed including this key point

Comment: not sure what effect that property has, but you could add a profile in that module that needs specific treatment, set the property within that profile and activate it via -P - but if its a custom property anyway and it cannot be the same why not just add another one?